# java.sql.Date is taking wrong date

Tags: java, date

I am using below code,

```
private static Date date = new Date (2014-1900,11,25); 
System.out.println(date);
```

It is displaying `2014-12-25`. I am unable to understand why it is giving me date as `12`?

and if i give

```
private static Date date = new Date (2014-1900,12,25);
```

it is returning `2015-01-25`.

Can anyone help in comprehend this?

Comment: Months are 0 based..

Comment: it's better to use the new java time api or if you can't upgrade to java 8 then use joda time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.MONTH)

It accept `December` month as `11` because month starts from `0 - 11`

Answer (score 1):

First you should not use this Constructor, because it is deprecated.

Second: See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(int,%20int,%20int)) of this consturctor:

> Parameters:year -
>   the year minus 1900.month - the month between 0-11.date - the day of
>   the month between 1-31.See Also:Calendar

month is a null based value, so 0 --> Jan ... 11 --> Dec

Answer (score 0):

from [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29),

```
Parameters:
year the year minus 1900.
month the month between 0-11.
date the day of the month between 1-31.
```

Month's range from `0-11, ie Jan - Dec`

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using the depriciated [Date()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) constructor for setting dates, It is recommended to use [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.NOVEMBER);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
Date date = calendar.getTime();
```

You can also use the [simpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for setting/formatting date values:-

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse("25-11-2014");
```

Comment: using a simpledateformat to initiate a date is just a waste of CPU cycle and possible threading issue

Comment: But it is better to waste a cpu cycle rather than wasting time setting dates using `new Date (2014-1900,11,25);` and wondering what went wrong.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check again and see if downvote is really necessary!